# Why the same code&data performance dramaticaly different? acc fluctuatee from 0.5 to 0.99

Tags: tensorflow, classification, deep-learning, lstm

My mode is tensorflow RNN LSTM model to classify two categories. training data:70000; testing data 10000.  batch_size 7.

But why the same code and the same data(all the things are the same), but the results are totally different. Sometimes the accuracy of testing dataset sticks in 0.5, or just have a little fluctuation near 0.5;but sometimes it could be 0.98 or 0.99. I changed the droupout, the learning rate, the optimizer, but there is no difference.

Could anyone tell me why? And how to solve it? Thanks very much.

Comment: What initializer are you using?

Comment: @martianwars just general initializer, 'init = tf.initialize_all_variables()', and the initialize values of biases are 0.1.